# How to set a value in EXT JS Combo Box using Selenium

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a ExtJS based UI. I have come to know that in ExtJS the combo box is not a real combo box but a combination of input text field, image of drop down box and a list. Now i am able to identify the control but i am stuck at selecting the value from the list.Coyuld you please help me out in setting the value of "**functional currency**" from the drop down
Please find the HTML Source code below

Please find the list of values in the Drop Down of Combo Box out of all these values in the drop down list i need to select any one value

AfghaniAlgerian DinarArgentine PesoArmenian DramAruban GuilderAustralian DollarAustrian SchillingAzerbaijanian ManatBahamian DollarBahraini DinarBalboaBarbados DollarBelarussian RubleBelgian FrancBelize DollarBermudian DollarBolivarBolivianoBrazilian RealBritish PoundBrunei DollarBulgarian LevBurundi FrancCanadian DollarCape Verde EscudoCayman Islands DollarCediCFA Franc BCEAOCFA Franc BEACCFP FrancChilean PesoColombian PesoComoro FrancConvertible MarksCordoba OroCosta Rican ColonCroatian KunaCuban PesoCyprus PoundCzech KorunaDalasiDanish KroneDenarDeutsche MarkDjibouti FrancDobraDominican PesoDongDutch GuilderEast Caribbean DollarEgyptian PoundEl Salvador ColonEthiopian BirrEuroFalkland Islands PoundFiji DollarFinnish MarkkaForintFranc CongolaisFrench FrancGibraltar PoundGold OuncesGourdeGreek DrachmaGuaraniGuernsey PoundGuinea FrancGuinea-Bissau PesoGuyana DollarHong Kong DollarHryvniaIceland KronaIndian RupeeIranian RialIraqi DinarIrish PuntIsle of Man PoundItalian LiraJamaican DollarJapanese YenJersey PoundJordanian DinarKenyan ShillingKinaKipKroonKuwaiti DinarKwachaKwachaKwanzaKyatLariLatvian LatLebanese PoundLekLempiraLeoneLiberian DollarLibyan DinarLilangeniLithuanian LitaLotiMalagasy AriaryMalaysian RinggitMaltese LiraMauritius RupeeMeticalMexican PesoMexican PesoMexican Unidad de Inversion (UID)Moldovan LeuMoroccan DirhamMvdolNairaNakfaNamibian DollarNepalese RupeeNetherlands Antillian GuilderNew Israeli SheqelNew Zealand DollarNgultrumNorth Korean WonNorwegian KroneNuevo SolOld LeuOuguiyaPa'angaPakistan RupeePalladium OuncesPatacaPeso UruguayoPhilippines PesoPlatinum OuncesPolish ZlotyPortuguese EscudoPulaQatari RialQuetzalRial OmaniRielRomanian LeuRufiyaaRupiahRussian RubleRwanda FrancSaint Helena PoundSaudi RiyalSDRSeborga, LuiginiSerbian DinarSeychelles RupeeSilver OuncesSingapore DollarSlovakia KorunaSolomon Islands DollarSomSomali ShillingSomoniSouth African RandSouth Korean WonSpanish PesetaSri Lanka RupeeSudanese DinarSurinam DollarSwedish KronaSwiss FrancSyrian PoundTaiwan DollarTakaTalaTanzanian ShillingTengeThai BahtTolarTrinidad and Tobago DollarTugrikTunisian DinarTurkish LiraTurkmenian ManatTuvalu DollarsUAE DirhamUganda ShillingUnidad de Valor RealUnidades de formentoUnited States DollarUzbekistan SumVatuYemeni RialYuan RenminbiZimbabwe Dollar